# converting % symbol to string in vba

Tags: vba, excel

My Question is simple:
all I want to do is add the "%" symbol to a cell that contains numerical data.
Here is the code that I wrote:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

 With Range("B11")
    .Select
    .Value = [B11] & ChrW(U + 37)
End With


End Sub
```

the result I get is that the numerical data gets divided by 100 and the % symbol is not added. I have tried to replace the ChrW(U + 37) with "%" but it doesn't work.
I am very new to vba so I need all the help I can get!

Comment: Do it as formatting, not as part of the value.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so do i need to change .value for .format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Cells(1, 5).NumberFormat = "0.00%"`, `Range("B11").NumberFormat = "0.00%"` or `[B11].NumberFormat = "0.00%"` to change formatting of a cell instead of trying to add character to a number. You might need to change the 0.00 to any other formatting type that suits your need.

You mentioned that the data is numerical and you probably want to keep it that way if you use it in calculations, changing of formatting should be your choice.

Comment: just be aware that when you change formatting from general to percent it multiplies value by 100 so 1 = 100%. If you have 10 in cell and want it to be converted directly to 10% divide your data by 100 first:
`[d1].Value = [d1].Value / 100`
`[d1].NumberFormat = "0.00%"`

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code, it is tested and works fine for me:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Sheet1.Cells(11, 2).Value = 200
    Sheet1.Cells(11, 2).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
End Sub
```

Comment: a bit late, please check answers before posting

Comment: page was not refreshed to check answers, and besides posting do not harm so it is not a competition dude

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your code, you probably need something like this:

```
[h6]= cstr([h6].text & ChrW(U + 37))
```

However, it just adds the symbol for H6.

Comment: this however will change your data from numerical that you had to a string